# Iif equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-operator, iif-function

Is there an `IIf` equivalent in C#? Or similar shortcut?

Comment: I think you meant "short cut", rather than "short circuit" (which has a specific meaning regarding boolean operators) - am I right?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

C# has the `?` ternary operator, like other C-style languages. However, this is not perfectly equivalent to `IIf()`; there are two important differences.

To explain the first difference, the false-part argument for this `IIf()` call causes a `DivideByZeroException`, even though the boolean argument is `True`.

```
IIf(true, 1, 1/0)
```

`IIf()` is just a function, and like all functions all the arguments must be evaluated before the call is made. Put another way, `IIf()` does *not* short circuit in the traditional sense. On the other hand, this ternary expression does short-circuit, and so is perfectly fine:

```
(true)?1:1/0;
```

The other difference is `IIf()` is not type safe. It accepts and returns arguments of type `Object`. The ternary operator *is* type safe. It uses type inference to know what types it's dealing with. Note you can fix this very easily with your own generic `IIF(Of T)()` implementation, but out of the box that's not the way it is.

If you really want `IIf()` in C#, you can have it:

```
object IIf(bool expression, object truePart, object falsePart) 
{return expression?truePart:falsePart;}
```

or a generic/type-safe implementation:

```
T IIf<T>(bool expression, T truePart, T falsePart) 
{return expression?truePart:falsePart;}
```

On the other hand, if you want the ternary operator in VB, Visual Studio 2008 and later provide a new `If()` *operator* that works like C#'s ternary operator. It uses type inference to know what it's returning, and it really is an operator rather than a function. This means there's no issues from pre-evaluating expressions, even though it has function semantics.

Comment: VB9 does support a true ternary operator.

If(SomeBool, MessageBox.Show("True"), MessageBox.Show("False"))

As seen here: http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/08/31/visual-basic-9-0-the-if-ternary-operator.aspx

Comment: I mention it in the last paragraph, but the question was specifically about IIf().

Answer (score 67):

VB.NET:

```
If(someBool, "true", "false")
```

C#

```
someBool ? "true" : "false";
```

Comment: While this is true for simple expressions, the two forms are not exactly equivalent if there are side effects in the alternative expressions. Iif(t, foo(), bar()) will call both foo() and bar(), while t ? foo() : bar() will only call either foo() or bar() but not both. See Joel Coehoorn's answer to this question for more information.

Comment: Updated answer to use VB.NET's "If" function instead of "IIf" so that the two code blocks are equivalent.

Answer (score 13):

the ternary operator

```
bool a = true;

string b = a ? "if_true" : "if_false";
```

Comment: i'd add a comment there that that's  string b= (a ? "asdf" : "dsrs");  i.e. then it's possible to better understand how the thing works, and to see that it's not something really weird and nonsensical like (string b=a) ? "sdf" : "sdsdf").

Answer (score 10):

Also useful is the coalesce operator ??:

VB:

```
Return Iif( s IsNot Nothing, s, "My Default Value" )
```

C#:

```
return s ?? "My Default Value";
```

Answer (score 6):

```
booleanExpression ? trueValue : falseValue;
```

Example:

```
string itemText = count > 1 ? "items" : "item";
```

http://zamirsblog.blogspot.com/2011/12/c-vb-equivalent-of-iif.html

Answer (score 1):

It's the ternary operator `?`

```
string newString = i == 1 ? "i is one" : "i is not one";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's limited in that you can't put statements in there. You can only put values(or things that return/evaluate to values),  to return

This works ('a' is a static int within class Blah)

```
Blah.a=Blah.a<5?1:8;
```

(round brackets are impicitly between the equals and the question mark).

This doesn't work.

```
Blah.a = Blah.a < 4 ? Console.WriteLine("asdf") : Console.WriteLine("34er");
or
Blah.a = Blah.a < 4 ? MessageBox.Show("asdf") : MessageBox.Show("34er");
```

So you can only use the c# ternary operator for returning values.  So it's not quite like a shortened form of an if.  Javascript and perhaps some other languages let you put statements in there.

Comment: Yes, because it's setting a value, not invoking a method.

You could use `Action` to do what you want though.

Comment: @KieranFoot   WriteLine is a method.  Been a while, but If `iif` or the ternary operator,  let you put a return value in there like `Blah.a = Blah.a < 4 ? Console.WriteLine("asdf");  return 1: Console.WriteLine("34er") ; return 2;`  then if it allowed that, it'd work, but apparently it doesn't. And yeah it's still setting a value, and no it's not calling any new method there.

Comment: You could easily make it an inline if that executes one of 2 actions as I said.