# What is IIF in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iif equivalent in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822810/iif-equivalent-in-c)

I have several lines of code using `IIf` in VB and I am trying to convert this code to C#.

Here's an example where I need help:

```
intCurrency = IIf(or.Fields("Currency").Value = "USD", 100, 0)
```

How do I change the above line of code to C#? Is there a short-circuit evaluation operator in C#?

Comment: For reference, `Iif` is *not* a short-circuit evaluation.  **The true and false expressions both get evaluated.**  Make sure whenever you use it, that the expressions have no side effects that you care about.  C#'s does only evaluate the corresponding expression, so that's something to watch for when you're converting.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is **close** to the C# ternary / conditional operator as several people have suggested but it is not an exact replacement.  The C# ternary operator does short circuit evaluation meaning that only the side effect of the evaluated clause occurs.  In VB.Net the `Iif` function does not implement short circuiting and will evaluate both side effects.

Additionally the `Iif` function in VB.Net is weakly typed.  It accepts and returns values typed as `Object`.  The C# ternary operator is strongly typed.

The closest equivalent you can write is the following.  Putting the values into the arguments forces the evaluation of their side effects.

```
public static object Iif(bool cond, object left, object right) {
  return cond ? left : right;
}
```

Or slightly more usable

```
public static T Iif<T>(bool cond, T left, T right) {
  return cond ? left : right;
}
```

Comment: +1, not only the closest equivalent, but I'd say exactly equivalent to the public Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIf method, as can be seen using Reflector. But just to be pedantic, in VB.NET, IIf is a function not an operator.

Comment: @Joe, Thanks for the correction, updated

Answer (score 18):

Yep, it's the question mark (A.K.A the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)).

```
intCurrency = or.Fields["Currency"].Value == "USD" ? 100 : 0;
```

Comment: Although you'l probably need to change those () to []. (on an unrelated point)

Comment: @josh3736 unfortunately that's not the equivalent.  The C# ternary operator is both short circuiting and strongly typed while the VB.Net `iif` operator is neither.

Comment: And you have to cast the operands to object.

Comment: It is, however, equivalent enough for most practical use; that is, at least in my experience.

Comment: @Jared `iif` is not even an operator, for that matter.

Comment: @Anton, true, it is just a runtime function.  Unfortunately my comment's been voted on so I can't edit it to correct it :(

Answer (score 5):

This is being incredibly pedantic, but the closest equivalent of `IIf` in C# is

```
intCurrency = ((Func<bool, object, object, object>)((x, y, z) => x ? y : z))(or.Fields["Currency"].Value == "USD", 100, 0);
```

However, I wonder if you are really interested in VB's ternary operator. So the following in VB

```
intCurrency = IIf(or.Fields("Currency").Value = "USD", 100, 0)
```

could be better written as (notice the difference between `IIf` and `If`)

```
intCurrency = If(or.Fields("Currency").Value = "USD", 100, 0)
```

which is exactly the same in C# as

```
intCurrency = or.Fields["Currency"].Value == "USD" ? 100 : 0;
```

Another interesting point is that `If` doubles as the null coalescing operator.

```
Dim text As String = Nothing
text = If(text, "Nothing")
```

which is exactly the same in C# as

```
string text = null;
text = text ?? "null";
```

Comment: to be super pedantic, the exact equivalent would use `object` instead of `int`.  The `IIF` operator is a holdover from VB7 which did not have generic support hence the arguments and return were typed as `object`

Comment: @JaredPar: Haha...totally. I'll fix that :)

Comment: @bcat: Thanks for being pedantic and fixing the spelling of "padantic" :)

Answer (score 3):

I know others have answered this... but I thought I'd clarify. If you're interested in more reading, it's called a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) or also commonly known as the conditional operator.

Comment: Thanks. That's the word I was looking for.

Comment: It isn't, it is called the conditional operator.  Which belongs to the group of ternary operators.  Small group.

Comment: @Hans Passant: It *is* called **a** ternary statement, though one might call it **the** conditional operator.

Comment: It is an operator, not a statement, and should **not** be called a statement

Comment: @Dario it's a minor point but @Hans is correct here.  The C# lang spec refers to this as the conditional operator (section 7.13) but notes it is also called the ternary operator.  It makes no mention of a ternary statement.  Ternary is only used in 2 sections of the spec.  The aforementioned and 7.2 where it states the ternary class of operators which has 1 member the conditional

Comment: wow, didn't think a misstatement (pun intended) like that would cause such a heated discussion... Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It's the ?: operator.

```
 or.Fields["Currency"].Value == "USD" ? 100 : 0;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
intCurrency = or.Fields["Currency"].Value == "USD" ? 100 : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ?: operator to do equivalent code:

```
intCurrency = or.Fields["Currency"].Value = "USD" ? 100 : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, you're looking for the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
intCurrency = or.Fields["Currency"].Value == "USD" ? 100 : 0;
```

However, just as a point of correction, this is not "short circuit evaluation". Short-circuit evaluation means that once a boolean expression can be reliably determined, no further evaluation is performed (this amounts to encountering a `true` condition in an `or` expression or a `false` condition in an `and` expression).

While it's possible to combine boolean expressions in the conditional operator just like you can in anything else (like an `if` statement) and that *expression* will employ short-circult evaluation, it doesn't have anything to do, *per se*, with the conditional operator.

An important distinction to note is that, while VB.NET's `Iif` function evaluates both the true and false expressions, C#'s conditional operator evaluates only the expression that is selected by the boolean condition (making it behave more like a traditional `if` expression). This could be important if the VB.NET code relied on both expressions being evaluated.

Comment: Possibly due to the () instead of []? I upvoted myself, but that's the only thing I can think of...

Comment: @Jon: Thanks, good catch. That's what I get for copying from the question!

Answer (score 0):

or.Fields("Currency").Value = "USD" ? 100 : 0