# Java Equivalent to iif function

Tags: java, function, if-statement, equivalent, iif-function

the question is simple, there is a functional equivalent of the famous iif in java?

For example:

```
IIf (vData = "S", True, False)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JJnguy: No, `iif` is an inline-if function that takes a boolean value as its first parameter, and when true returns the second parameter, and when false returns the third parameter.

Comment: For posterity: Please note that the accepted answer is not actually correct with respect to short-circuiting.  Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822810/iif-equivalent-in-c instead ...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
vData.equals("S") ? true : false
```

or in this particular case obviously one could just write

```
vData.equals("S")
```

Comment: **Especially** the second bit. That's not so obvious to a lot of people.

Comment: This isn't quite the same thing. Using `IIF(x, y, z)` will always evaluate `y` and `z` (causing side-effects of both to be visible), while `x ? y : z` will only evaulate `y` xor `z` (causing the side-effects of only one to be visible).

Comment: @Gabe: VB doesn't support short-circuit evaluation in general. Although VB.NET does

Comment: Thanks Adrian, all answers helped me.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, the ternary op `? :`

```
vData.equals("S") ? true : false
```

Answer (score 4):

The main difference between the Java ternary operator and `IIf` is that `IIf` evaluates **both** the returned value and the unreturned value, while the ternary operator short-circuits and evaluates only the value returned.  If there are side-effects to the evaluation, the two are not equivalent.

You can, of course, reimplement `IIf` as a static Java method.  In that case, both parameters will be evaluated at call time, just as with `IIf`.  But there is no builtin Java language feature that equates exactly to `IIf`.

```
public static <T> T iif(boolean test, T ifTrue, T ifFalse) {
    return test ? ifTrue : ifFalse;
}
```

(Note that the `ifTrue` and `ifFalse` arguments *must* be of the same type in Java, either using the ternary operator or using this generic alternative.)

Comment: thanks, I understand, similar to the function AndAlso, OrElse in VB NET, right?

Comment: Yes, that's another example of short-circuiting.

Answer (score 2):

if is the same as the logical iff.

```
boolean result;
if (vData.equals("S"))
   result = true;
else
   result = false;
```

or

```
boolean result = vData.equals("S") ? true : false;
```

or

```
boolean result = vData.equals("S");
```

EDIT: However its quite likely you don't need a variable instead you can act on the result. e.g.

```
if (vData.equals("S")) {
   // do something
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

BTW it may be considered good practice to use

```
 if ("S".equals(vData)) {
```

The difference being that is vData is null the first example will throw an exception whereas the second will be false. You should ask yourself which would you prefer to happen.