# what does question mark mean in these codes?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, flutter

these source code is from flutter tutorial

Widget _buildRow(WordPair pair) {
  final bool alreadySaved = _saved.contains(pair);
  return new ListTile(
    title: new Text(
      pair.asPascalCase,
      style: _biggerFont,
    ),
    trailing: new Icon(   // Add the lines from here... 
      alreadySaved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
      color: alreadySaved ? Colors.red : null,
    ),                    // ... to here.
  );
}

what does this part mean?
trailing: new Icon(   // Add the lines from here... 
      alreadySaved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
      color: alreadySaved ? Colors.red : null,
    ),                    // ... to here.
can someone make another form of this code but with the same logic? I don't understand this part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the ternary operator (or short-if). For example the following is equivalent:

```
if (COND) {
   X = A;
} else {
   X = B;
}

X = COND ? A : B; // if COND condition is met, execute A, otherwise execute B
```

See this [article](https://kodechamp.com/ternary-operator/).

In your example if the variable `alreadySaved` is true the `Icons.favorite` is used as well as `Colors.red`. If `alreadySaved` is false, then `Icons.favorite_border` is used together with `null` for the color.

Answer (score 2):

It is an immediate if, so it basically means if  then assign first value, else (marked by ':') assign second value.

simple example:

```
x = True? 1 : 2
```

will assign 1

```
x = False? 1: 2
```

will assign 2

Also see this question:
[Java Equivalent to iif function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684976/java-equivalent-to-iif-function)