# Calculation in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Chauffeur service cost $30. It is an option to user whether they want the service or not. When they already select car, and day of rental, I store it in session.

```
Session["car1"] = Label1.Text;
Session["price"] = Label5.Text;
Session["day"] = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text;
Session["driver"] = Label6.Text;
Response.Redirect("~/Welcome/BookingForm.aspx");
```

Then in bookingform.aspx, I retrieve back the session, and display it in label.

```
string car1 = Session["car1"].ToString();
string price = Session["price"].ToString();
string day = Session["day"].ToString();
string driver = Session["driver"].ToString();
```

To calculate the total amount of user should pay, I used this code:

```
int totalValue = 0;
totalValue = int.Parse(Session["price"].ToString()) *
             int.Parse(Session["day"].ToString());
Label8.Text = totalValue.ToString();
```

The problem now is, I don't know how to add $30 for chauffeur service IF user pick that service. Like if user choose yes, totalValue + 30, and if NO, do nothing.

Thanks for your time. Cheers.

Comment: How does the user select whether he wants that service or not? just hold another session variable for that.

Comment: I provide it in dropdown list. User can select yes or No

Comment: Then save the dropdown list's selected option in session also and use it in next page.

Comment: Using Session variables in this manner seems like you need to rethink your design (unless it can't be avoided).
I also suggest renaming your identifiers. Label1, Label2 means nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you create a custom class, add the properties like Car, Price, Day, ChaffterUsed etc. Create the object of the class, fill the properties and store the object into session. On next page, load the object from session and use it.

Answer (score 3):

Store the  dropdown value into another session variable say IsChaffeurUsed. Make it a boolean.

```
bool IsChauffeurUsed= dropDown.SelectedValue=="Yes" ? true :false;
Session["IsChauffeurUsed"]= IsChauffeurUsed;


//Your logic to compute total

int totalValue = 0;
totalValue = int.Parse(Session["price"].ToString()) *
             int.Parse(Session["day"].ToString());

//check if chaffeur service is used

bool isChaffeurUsed = (bool) Session["IsChaffeurUsed"]; 

    if(isChaffeurUsed)
        {
        total += 30;
        }
Label8.Text = (totalValue).ToString();
```

Comment: I dont know how to do it. Can u pls epxlain more.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use Server.Transfer() instead of Response.Redirect() and use PreviousPage to fetch your required values.

This will save you from using Session as Session should not be used in this scenario.

To know how to use PreviousPage see below link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you provide to select the service in a dropdown, why not store that status in session as well ?
Like

```
bool chauffeurService= YourServiceDropDown.SelectedValue=="1" ? true :false;
Session["chauffeurStatus"]=chauffeurService;
```

Then inside your form where to process values

```
// Check if Chauffer service status is 1 add 30 dollars else don't add anything
```

Comment: Status of Chauffer can be either true or false so you can use a boolean & store that in Session then check the session & add 30 dollars where necessary. Can you pinpoint exactly what you don't understand?

Comment: Act I dont know how to write the code in my system. This is so embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

totalValue = int.Parse(Session["price"].ToString()) *   int.Parse(Session["day"].ToString()) + ShowFerInUse ? 30 : 0;

This way you can use [iif equivalent in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822810/iif-equivalent-in-c-sharp) and do ShowFerInUse at same time.