# calculation in boolean

Tags: c#, asp.net, boolean

I have a drop down list where I stored 3 elements inside it.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                Height="22px" Width="134px">
                <asp:ListItem>Please Choose</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

When user choose Yes in drop down, the YES will be stored in session. Chauffeur service will charge user $30.

```
    Session["IsChauffeurUsed"] = DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Selected;
```

The thing is what to do if user select YES the the current amount that user have to pay is

```
    int totalValue = 0;
    int total = 0;
    totalValue = int.Parse(Session["price"].ToString()) * int.Parse(Session["day"].ToString()); 
    Label8.Text = totalValue.ToString();
```

***Label8.text will be plus 30 (if user select yes)**

I got stuck at the bold line. I dont know how to add 30 in totalValue if user select YES I hope u guys can help me. Cheers.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It isn't clear.

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: If `Session["IsChauffeurUsed"]` equals "Y", add 30 to total value, now where are you stuck at ?

Comment: I believe that this question has already been asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754489/calculation-in-code-behind/11754647#11754647

Comment: @Umesh, yeap, but i didnt get the answer yet. So, i re-post it so that new comers will look at my prob. Thanks for your concern. :)

Comment: @Stuck, I guess you got the answer in that post itself by Vinoth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that i find it horrible to take something, call `ToString()` on it and afterwards `Type.Parse()` on this string you could solve the problem as follows:

```
totalValue = int.Parse(Session["price"].ToString()) * int.Parse(Session["day"].ToString()); 
totalValue += Session["IsChauffeurUsed"].ToString().Equals("yes", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? 30 : 0;
```

Comment: Hi @Oliver, I get this error when applying your code. Member 'object.Equals(object, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: @Stuck: Must be something with your `Session` or sth else. This dummy doesn't throw any errors: `int test = "test".ToString().Equals("yes", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? 30 : 0;`

Answer (score 2):

You have to check you session value (If needed Add check for null) and then conditionally add the value

```
If (Session["IsChauffeurUsed"].ToString() == "Yes")
      totalValue +=30 ;
Label8.Text = totalValue.ToString();
```