# How to use an Iif Statement in an Expression

Tags: c#

I have this line of code in c#
I keep getting this error=>
**Syntax error: Missing operand before '&' operator.**

Find below is my code

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("RESULTS").Expression = "Iif(((ActualWeight >= (.96 * TargetWeight)) && (ActualWeight <= (1.04 * TargetWeight))),[GOOD] )";
```

Comment: are you sure its with that line of code? and post more code. What is Expression? is it a string, Expression?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iif equivalent in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822810/iif-equivalent-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Yes @Alex ,I had used without knowing it was not valid in c# , what can do to tweak it in c# mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DataTable Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) are more like VB than C#.  The && is not supported by `And` is:

```
ds.Tables[0]
  .Columns
  .Add("RESULTS")
  .Expression = "Iif(((ActualWeight >= (.96 * TargetWeight)) And (ActualWeight <= (1.04 * TargetWeight))),[GOOD],null)";
```

Note that I also added a `false` condition to complete the expression.

Comment: Hi Stanley, I am getting Syntax error: Invalid number of arguments: function Iif().

Comment: @Sheldon Did you add a false expression (the third parameter)?

Comment: @Sheldon Look at the end of my example.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `false` part of the expression as well as `Iif` is not syntactically correct. so try something like this

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("RESULTS").Expression = "IIF(((ActualWeight >= (.96 * TargetWeight)) And (ActualWeight <= (1.04 * TargetWeight))),[GOOD], [BAD])"
```

Comment: Hi @ Sachin am getting =>Syntax error: Missing operand before '&' operator.

Comment: Thanks @ Sachin y'all are amazing