# In C# How to concatenate values with strings in RDLC IIf expression?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, expression, concatenation, rdlc

I have an RDLC Report file in which I want to make an expression. I want to use **IIf** function here...

**=IIf(First(Fields!due.Value, "DataSet1") = 0 ,"FULL PAID","DUE TK ="+First(Fields!due.Value, "DataSet1")+".00")**

When the condition is true it shows FULL PAID but when False it Shows #Error 
It seems there is concatenation problem

**=IIf(First(Fields!due.Value, "DataSet1") = 0 ,"FULL PAID",First(Fields!due.Value, "DataSet1"))**

When the condition is true it shows FULL PAID but when False it Shows only value
Now I need to know that is it possible to concat string with dataset values here...

**RDLC REPORT FOR BILL PRINT**
[image: RDLC REPORT FOR BILL PRINT]

Comment: Please check this, maybe it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822810/iif-equivalent-in-c-sharp

Comment: I believe you need to convert your First(Fields!due.Value, "DataSet1")) to a string with CStr or Format in order to concatenate it.